# How to show Notification text in status bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to show text of a notification in status bar like in this picture:

[image]

But instead I get the following:

[image]

So, as you can see, I can't show the text in status bar, only icon. My code looks like this:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("My app")
            .setTicker("Alex: hey, want to grab lunch?")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText("Alex: hey, want to grab lunch?")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

How do I correct that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what version of Android the app is run on. If it's Lollipop (5.0) or above, then no, the text will not appear in the status bar. [From the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerText) (my bold):

> Text that summarizes this notification for accessibility services. **As of the L release, this text is no longer shown on screen, but it is still useful to accessibility services** (where it serves as an audible announcement of the notification's appearance).

So it's still worth having as it'll be read out to anyone who uses text-to-speech accessibility services on their phone. It just won't work in the way you're expecting it to in your question.

Alternatively, if you want your notification to appear briefly as a [heads-up notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up), you can set your notification's priority to [`PRIORITY_HIGH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_HIGH) (up to API 26):

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    ...
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .build();
```

You may also need to use a [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) rather than `Notification.Builder` if this doesn't work.